# Different slurp behavior with "lein run" and running the uberjar file

Tags: clojure, leiningen, uberjar

I am currently trying to learn Clojure and as part of my practical training, I am
implementing the very basic behavior of some of the well known Unix tools like `grep`,
`cat`, `ls` and so on.

While implementing `cat`, I stumbled upon some seemingly strange behavior of
`slurp`. When I run the following code with `lein run some-file.txt` while `some-file.txt`
lies within the current directory, the content is printed to STDOUT as expected.

```
(ns cat.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  "Reads the content of its arguments representing filenames and outputs the
  content in succession."
  [& filenames]
  (doseq [filename filenames]
    (println "Reading" filename) ; Just for debugging purposes
    (print (slurp filename))))
```

However, if I `uberjar` the project with

```
lein compile
lein uberjar
```

and then `cd` to `target/uberjar` to run the standalone JAR with
`java -jar cat-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar some-file.txt` (with the text file present in that directory),
nothing but my debug message gets printed. What I find so strange is that there is no error
message being shown, so it seems to me that the file can be found. If I run the
JAR with a file that does not exist as parameter, I get an exeption that the specified
file cannot be found (as expected).

Because I am working on a Windows machine, a colleague suggested that perhaps Windows
shadow files might be a problem. So I tested the program under Linux again and the
same behavior occured. So this seems to be a "problem" with my Clojure understanding / my project
settings.

My question is: Why is `slurp`'s (or the program's) behavior different when running
with `lein run` and when running the standalone JAR with `java -jar cat-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar` and what can I do to solve this?

As the file parameter is not a resource that is compiled into the JAR, there is no
need for `(slurp (clojure.java.io/resource filename))` if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print` does not flush the output buffer.  You need to use `flush` after your `print` statement, or use another `println`, which flushes on newline:

```
(defn -main
  "Reads the content of its arguments representing filenames and outputs the
  content in succession."
  [& filenames]
  (doseq [filename filenames]
    (print (slurp filename))
    (flush)))
```

Comment: In order to fully mimic `cat`'s behavior, I'd choose to use `flush` instead of `println` (`cat` doesn't insert additional newline after output)

Comment: Agreed!  I edited to show the `flush` instead of the `println`.  Thanks, @OlegTheCat